# Different type libraries for different versions

Tags: c#, dll

in my c# project I'm using a type library of an third party software to communicate that software. But when someone uses an older Version of the third party software then I have to load another type library (an older one) how can I handle this?

And the next thing is, that in the type library may be some changes so my actual code doesnt work (maybe!!)

Comment: When you say "type library", do you mean a COM library? If it's designed properly according to guidelines, all you need is to take the lowest-version interface that you need and use that, no juggling necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should create an Interface, which wraps the functionality of your thirdparty library. If you do so, you can have 2 implementations of that interface. One for each Version of the third party library.

```
public interface IWrapThirdParty {
  void ThirdPartyMethodOne(); 
  int ThirdPartyMethodTwo();
}

 public class ThirdPartyV1Wrapper : IWrapThirdParty {
  public void ThirdPartyMethodOne() {
    ThirdPartyV1 obj = new ThirdPartyV1();
    obj.ThirdPartyMethodOne();
  }
  public int ThirdPartyMethodTwo(){
    ThirdPartyV1 obj = new ThirdPartyV1();
    return obj.ThirdPartyMethodTwo();
  }
}
```

---

To solve your problem with loading the libraries:

You can use the Assembly.Load() method after u figured out, which Version u want to load. But be aware to NEVER load an assembly 2 times.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.load(v=vs.110).aspx

---

To check if the assembly is allready loaded u can use the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() Method, which will return all assemblies that are currently loaded into the AppDomain.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.getassemblies(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: okay so i need to implement a wrapper for each version like "ThirdPartyV2Wrapper, ThirdPartyV3Wrapper"?

Comment: Yep, atleast that is what i do, when i'm working with third party libraries. Works pretty well for me :)

Comment: If i was able to answer your question i'd be happy if you accept the answer :)